# Extracting subimage with a specified aspect ratio

Tags: c++, python, algorithm, matlab, image-processing

I need to extract an object from an image. I know the location of the object inside the image, ie the region where the object is located: this region is provided as a pair of coordinates *[xmin, ymin]* and *[xmax, ymax]*.

I would like to modify the coordinates of this region (thus increasing the height and width in a suitable way) in order to extract a subimage with a specified aspect ratio. So, we have the following constraints:

1. in order to avoid cutting the object incorrectly, the width and height of the region must not be reduced;
2. bounds checking: the adaptation of the region size must ensure that the new coordinates are inside the image;
3. the *width/height* ratio of the subimage should be approximately equal to the specified aspect ratio.

How to solve this problem?

**UPDATE: one possible solution**

The solution to my problem is mainly the algorithm proposed by Mark in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15348901/364056). The result of this algorithm is a new region wider or higher than the original and it is able to obtain a new aspect ratio very close to that specified, without moving the center of the original region (if this is feasible, depending on the position of the region within the original image). The region obtained from this algorithm could be further processed by the following algorithm in order to make the aspect ratio closer to that specified.

```
for left=0:(xmin-1),                      // it tries all possible combinations
    for right=0:(imgWidth-xmax),          // of increments of the region size
        for top=0:(ymin-1),               // along the four directions
            for bottom=0:(imgHeight-ymax),
                x1 = xmin - left;
                x2 = xmax + right;
                y1 = ymin - top;
                y2 = ymax + bottom;

                newRatio = (x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1);

                if (newRatio == ratio)
                    rect = [x1 y1 x2 y2];
                    return;
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

***Example...*** An image with 976 rows and 1239 columns; an initial region [xmin ymin xmax ymax] = [570 174 959 957].

First algorithm (*main processing*).

- Input: the initial region and the image size.
- Output: it produces new region r1 = [568 174 960 957],
  width = 392 and height = 783, so the aspect ratio is equal to 0.5006.

Second algorithm (*post-processing*).

- Input: the region r1.
- Output: new region r2 = [568 174 960 958],
  width = 392 and height = 784, so the aspect ratio is equal to 0.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
obj_width = xmax - xmin
obj_height = ymax - ymin
if (obj_width / obj_height > ratio)
{
    height_adjustment = ((obj_width / ratio) - (ymax - ymin)) / 2;
    ymin -= height_adjustment;
    ymax += height_adjustment;
    if (ymin < 0)
    {
        ymax -= ymin;
        ymin = 0;
    }
    if (ymax >= image_height)
        ymax = image_height - 1;
}
else if (obj_width / obj_height < ratio)
{
    width_adjustment = ((obj_height * ratio) - (xmax - xmin)) / 2;
    xmin -= width_adjustment;
    xmax += width_adjustment;
    if (xmin < 0)
    {
        xmax -= xmin;
        xmin = 0;
    }
    if (xmax >= image_width)
        xmax = image_width - 1;
}
```

Comment: The final ratio is not exactly equal to that specified, but I am aware that it is not always possible to achieve this goal (because the boundaries of the image can not be exceeded). In fact, I have developed an algorithm to calculate the exact ratio (obviously also in this case, the boundaries of the image does not always allow this), but it shifts the center of the new region from the original position. I like this algorithm because it allows to increase the width or height, trying not to move the center of the original region. So I thought of putting the two algorithms in cascade.

Comment: @enzom83, I don't understand your reasoning. This algorithm should produce the exact ratio if it's possible, shifting the position if necessary. Even if the exact ratio isn't possible it should get as close as the constraints allow. I'd appreciate it if you have an example where it produces less than optimal results.

Comment: I added the _post-processing algorithm_ and an example. I would be grateful if you tell me what you think of putting the two algorithms in cascade.

Comment: @enzom83, your post processing algorithm is going to be very slow, and there are cases where you will never get an exact match to the desired ratio because it's impossible or because floating point approximation will make you miss it. My algorithm as is should always get you within 2 pixels of the ideal if the constraints allow it, and with a little tweaking could get to within 1 pixel.

Comment: You're right, my algorithm is very slow. Precisely for this reason I apply my algorithm on the result returned by your faster algorithm. What is the little tweaking as you mentioned? How do you calculate the accuracy (in pixel) of the algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with your region: a *w* x *h* rectangle centered on a point *p*. You want to extend this region to have the aspect ratio *r*. The idea is to extend the width or the height:

1. (trivial case) If *w* / *h* == *r*, then return.
2. Compute *w'* = *h* x *r*.

   - If *w'* > *w*, then the resulting region is of width *w'*, height *h* and center *p*.
   - Else, the resulting region is of width *w*, height *h'* = *w* / *r*, and center *p*.
3. Move the center *p* to follow the edges of the image if it has to be clipped, for example if the resulting region upper-left point is outside of the image: let *u* = upper-left point of the resulting region and *d* = (min(*u.x*,0), min(*u.y*,0)). Then, the final center will be *p'* = *p* - *d*. It is similar for the lower-right part of the region.
4. Clip the resulting region to the image.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem in cases where enlarging the region so that it matches the desired aspect ratio causes it to overlap one or more edges of the image.

Comment: @GarethRees It does, case 3. I'm detailing this part at the moment, to be more explicit.

Comment: In case 3, the enlarged region might be wider than the image, so there would be nowhere for you to move the centre to.

Comment: @GarethRees, Yes, but there would be no solutions in that case, as width / height should not be reduced.

Comment: In such a case you need do the best you can under the constraints by setting the width of the region to the width of the image. See Mark Ransom's answer.

Comment: @GarethRees: if the enlarged region is wider than the image, the 3 point will move it to follow one edge, and then the clipping will give the region the width of the image.